# export grid view to existing pdf templete c#

Tags: c#, pdf, gridview, bind

I am reading data from database in grid view and try to bind the same gridview in a previously created pdf templete, but i am not sure how to do that.

Is there a possible way to do that in c#.

Answer (score 0):

iTextSharp is a good library for create pdf file in c# and asp.net. it's fully optional and have a lot of document

Comment: but use version 4.1.6 for commercial use

Answer (score 0):

Using itextsharp you can create a pdf document
You can loop through the gridview and populate a table in the pdf file.

```
int[] clmwidths111 = { 30, 20 };

    PdfPTable tbl14 = new PdfPTable(2);

    tbl14.SetWidths(clmwidths111);

    tbl14.WidthPercentage = 70;
    tbl14.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    tbl14.SpacingBefore = 25;
    tbl14.SpacingAfter = 10;
    tbl14.DefaultCell.Border = 1;


foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(((Literal)row.FindControl("Totalprem1")).Text, bodyFont2));
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            cell.Colspan = 1;
            cell.Border = 0;
            tbl14.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(((Literal)row.FindControl("Totalcom1")).Text, bodyFont2));
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
            cell.Colspan = 1;
            cell.Border = 0;
            tbl14.AddCell(cell);

        }

    }
```